# Not able to play Video using Test Cafe, Click event is doing nothing

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe

Not able to play Video using Test Cafe, Click event is not playing video. I am able to hover till specific element but when i click it should start playing the video. But it is unable to play.

````
const logger = RequestLogger({ url: 'URL', method: 'post' },
  { logResponseBody: true, logRequestBody: true, stringifyResponseBody: true, stringifyRequestBody: true });

const obj = 'URL';
await t.navigateTo(obj.uri);
const loader = Selector('.web_player_loader.loader');
await t.expect(loader.exists).notOk({ timeout: 30000 });
console.log('Video Started....');
const playerBase=Selector('.player-base');
await t.hover(playerBase);
await t.click(playerBase);

console.log('Logger Request Length is ',logger.requests.length);```

I am running the script using following params.

testcafe chrome --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required ./tests -s takeOnFails=true --skip-js-errors=true

Getting this error in the Console.

main.dad0fa6441f0af49d386.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'topLPVs' of undefined
    at t.value (main.dad0fa6441f0af49d386.js:2)
    at e.value (main.dad0fa6441f0af49d386.js:2)
    at e.value (main.dad0fa6441f0af49d386.js:2)
    at t.<anonymous> (main.dad0fa6441f0af49d386.js:2)
    at l (vendor~main.58.ac1d1027b98ee8b3b2d1.js:9)
    at Generator._invoke (vendor~main.58.ac1d1027b98ee8b3b2d1.js:9)
    at Generator.next (vendor~main.58.ac1d1027b98ee8b3b2d1.js:9)
    at n (hammerhead.js:15)
    at value (hammerhead.js:6)
    at n (vendor~main.58.ac1d1027b98ee8b3b2d1.js:2)
    at a (vendor~main.58.ac1d1027b98ee8b3b2d1.js:2)
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the callstack you provided, it looks like the error occurs in your application. This behavior can occur because testcafe clicks faster than an end user and initialization code on the tested page might not have sufficient time to complete. Could you please clarify if the same error occurs if you add a delay between hover and click actions?

```
t.hover(playerBase)
 .wait(1000)
 .click(playerBase);
```

If the error is reproduced, could you share an example showing it? I will research it locally.

Answer (score 0):

There was issue with the execution command. Earlier I was using testcafe chrome --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required src/tests/*.js -s takeOnFails=true. But now i have changed it to testcafe 'chrome --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required' src/tests/*.js -s takeOnFails=true and it worked.